# Query database with Perl return integer and not a string

Tags: perl

Consider the following Perl code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBD::mysql;
use Data::Dumper;
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database', 'user', 'password') or die "Can't connect to MySQL";
$sql = "SELECT OdL_ID FROM OdLs LIMIT 1";
$OdL_ID = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql);
print Data::Dumper->Dump([$OdL_ID]);
```

On my "old" SLES 11 SP4 it returns:

```
$VAR1 = '386379';
```

On my "new" openSUSE Leap 15.3 it returns:

```
$VAR1 = 386379;
```

How can I force my "new" openSUSE Leap 15.3 to return a string and not an integer? (Note that I have a lot of Perl scripts that have this problem!)

Comment: Please read [perlnumber](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber) and particularly [Numeric operators and numeric conversions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber#Numeric-operators-and-numeric-conversions). Perl uses that representation of the number which best fit for current operation. Note: in your code it is sufficient to use `print Dumper($OdL_ID);`.

Comment: Do you really need `Dumper` here? Maybe try just `print $OdL_ID`?

Comment: `CAST` the field to a `VARCHAR` or stringify the returned value (e.g. by concatenating it with the empty string)

Comment: Note that the use of quotes by DD doesn't necessarily indicate a string.

Comment: Hi

I am migrating a web application (perl, mysql, apache, jeasyui) from "SLES 11 SP4" to "openSUSE Leap 15.3".
All is ok.
The only problem is with jeasyui.
In different points of my application I get the following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toLowerCase is not a function"

Comment: I found that the problem is beacause of a json string.
In my "old" server the json string is: [{"OdL_ID":"386379"}]
In my "new" server the json string is: [{"OdL_ID":386379}]

The reason of this difference is because in my old server OdL_ID is returned as string ($VAR1 = '386379') but in my new server OdL_ID is returned as integer ($VAR1 = 386379)

Comment: In the database OdL_ID is defined as "int", then probably the "new" server return the correct string.

A possible solution is to convert all this values from int to string.
But perhaps there is a quicker solution.

regards
Miche

Answer (score 1):

I am migrating from a web application (perl, mysql, apache, jeasyui) from "SLES 11 SP4" to "openSUSE Leap 15.3".
All is ok.
The only problem is with jeasyui.

In different points of my application I get the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toLowerCase is not a function"

I found that the problem is beacause of a json string. In my "old" server the json string is: `[{"OdL_ID":"386379"}]` In my "new" server the json string is: `[{"OdL_ID":386379}]`.

The reason of this difference is because in my old server OdL_ID is returned as string (`$VAR1 = '386379'`) but in my new server OdL_ID is returned as integer (`$VAR1 = 386379`).

In the database OdL_ID is defined as "int", then probably the "new" server return the correct string.

A possible solution is to convert all this values from int to string.
But perhaps there is a quicker solution.